# Wordpress is installed in a subfolder with another install in the root. The subfolder requires root/index.php/page permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a group of wordpress sites. There is an install in the root that uses permalinks as expected, eg /%postname%/ = root/postname for the URL. In the subfolder installs that structure results in a 404 error, but if I structure the links to include /index.php/%postname%/ they work just fine. This just started happening today after having run fine for about two months.

Things I've done to try and get the subfolder sites working again:

- Rewritten the htaccess,
- Insured mod_rewrite was active
- Deactivated all the plugins for the subfolder install
- Tried various permalink structures (all result in 404)
- Installed a backup from when it was working
- Created new sites in subfolders and tested navigation with the same results
- Deactivated Wordfence in the root install and all plugins in a cloned subfolder test site

On the same server I am able to create sites in a subfolder under a different URL whose permalink structure works as expected.

Has anyone experienced this or have suggestions on what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to fix this problem and moved the site into a subdomain where it is currently running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem because in the root, next to index.php an index.html was installed.. Can you check?

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Considering the amount of information, it is more an answer... the index.php in the permalinks gives me an indication that there might be an index.html present...

Comment: There is no index.html in the root or in the subfolder in which the problem site is installed.

Comment: What changed on the moment the site broke? Did you perform an update? Where the servers updated?

Comment: The only new thing introduced was Wordfence Premium. I deleted it, checked that all the tables were removed from the database and that .user.ini and the additional file it places in the root were removed. Still no effect. Late at night I even tried reverting to default theme and turning off plugins, which had no effect. I tried using a different version of php.... no effect. My working theory is that maybe Wordfence made some changes the firewall settings that I can't find. I think I will back up the site, delete the subscription, and reinstall from the ground up.

Comment: And what if you delete the htaccess file and reflush the permalinks?